# android - Постоянное подключение к серверу

Tags: android

Хочу написать простую игрушку в которой будет реализован поиск игрока и игра с ним. Все должно быть без сбоев, тоесть подключение должно быть постоянное. Как это возможно реализовать? `HttpUrlConnection` и потоки? Или может какая-нибудь библиотека? Нужно, чтобы была какая-то сессия? Объясните пожалуйста и ткните нсом куда копать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP/IP соединение, но нужно учесть что Android в основном используется для **мобильных** устройств, соответственно имеем все прелести GSM/GPRS, и "ни единого разрыва" не получится

Comment: не удастся в гейплее самой игры обыграть ситуацию потери связи ? такая типа дополненная реальность

Comment: на сколько я знаю, TCP/IP - это набор протоколов для передачи данных, а не ПОСТОЯННОЕ ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ,

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте соединение на сокетах. Это по сути стандартное решение для поддержки постоянной связи